# Better if/else statement

Tags: c#

This works for any language, but I tagged c# because thats what Im using at this time.

I have some statements that I want to run when either of 2 conditions are true, but then some additional special statements depending on which was true (only one can be true)

```
if( condition1 || condition2 )
{
    statement1;
    statement2;

    if( condition1 )
        additional_statement1;
    else // (condition2)
        additional_statement2;
}
```

This just seems sloppy (I test for "condition1" twice) and only used the OR statement because I wanted the same response from both conditions, but now an enhancement needs the response to be slightly different.  Anyway to pretty this up?

Comment: This might be better fit for codereview?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review. Check codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Note that both condition1 and condition2 might be true.  Do you want additional_statement2 to execute in that case?  As you may already be aware, the code you have provided does not do that.

Comment: @Almo Its not really a code review, you could almost ask the question without any code at all, the code is just illustrative.

Comment: a switch statement could probably also work

Comment: @TheWobbuffet Only if condition1/condition2 are doing equality checks against constants, which is actually a very small subset of use cases for if statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That approach isn't really *that* bad. `if` statements are pretty cheap and fast, as long as the conditional expressions themselves are cheap and fast. That being said, you could wrap the common functionality into a function:

```
if (condition1)
{
   CommonFunction();
   //CustomStuff
}
else if (condition2)
{
    CommonFunction();
    //Other stuff
}
```

This avoids a copy-paste problem and has minimal execution of conditional expressions.

Comment: ...are pretty cheap and fast *provided the boolean expression (for example, `condition1`) is cheap and fast*.

Comment: @phoog Absolutely. I'll add that in.

Comment: switch statements are much neater.

Comment: @AndrewGrinder Switch statements can't be performed on variable expressions. Yes, it would work if the conditions were like `x == 1`, but many conditional expressions are more complex.